# Laravel whereRaw - how to escape a '?'

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, escaping

Is there a way to escape a "?" in a eloquent whereRaw Statement? (Using laravel 6.x)

example:

```
ExampleModel::whereRaw(' "table"."json_field"::jsonb ?| array[\'test\', \'test2\'] ')->get();
```

This gets sent to the db as

```
where "table"."json_field"::jsonb $1| array['test', 'test2']
```

And well, thats not what i wanted to query...

Tried with '\?', put it in a binding ([Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-methods)) - still no success.
Also i didn't find a reference in the docs ...

In my Usecase i want it to compare a json object with the psql comparing "?|" ([Postgres Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

the question is pretty old but my answer might help anyway.

The solution is very simple: just escape the questionmark with another questionmark.

The code of your example would look like this:

```
ExampleModel::whereRaw(' "table"."json_field"::jsonb ??| array[\'test\', \'test2\'] ')->get();
```

This solution has been tested with Laravel 7.28.3.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test but try using PDO:

```
$whereRaw = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote(' "table"."json_field"::jsonb ?| array["test", "test2"] ');

ExampleModel::whereRaw($whereRaw)->get();
```

Comment: sadly not working, now the whereRaw gets inserted  with "too much quotes" : 
`select * from table where ' "table"."json_field"::jsonb ?| array[''test'', ''test2''] '`

Comment: already tried, but that wasn't the quote we're looking for ;-)
The Failing quotation mark is after the where clause :
`[...]where *'* "table"."json[...]`


@edit the stars are "highlighting" the failing qoute

Answer (score -1):

Well, didn't find an answer, but a workaround:

> **Don't use the question mark operators!**

Instead i went for the named function. I found the named function via

```
SELECT 
  oprname, 
  oprcode || '(' || format_type(oprleft,  NULL::integer) || ', ' 
                 || format_type(oprright, NULL::integer) || ')' AS function
FROM pg_operator 
WHERE oprname = '?|';
```

( Found there: [big thanks to this guys post!](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/533#issuecomment-436223985))

So my Eloquent query now looks like:

```
ExampleModel::whereRaw('jsonb_exists_any("table"."json_field"::jsonb, array[\'test\', \'test2\'])')->get();
```

At least its working ¯\_(ツ)_/¯